# sphinx GROUP BY

Tags: php, sphinx

Going to illustrate this so please bear with me.

This is my MYSQL Table structure indexed by sphinx

```
------- ------- --------------
tag_id | tag   | foreign_id  |
------- ------- --------------
1       love     111
2       blue     222
3      lover     333
4       yellow   444
5       love     555
6       lov      666
```

What I'm trying to get from sphinx when I query "love" is something like this:

```
love = 2 hit
lover = 1 hit
```

Anyone has any idea how that can be done? I tried the following php code but all it output is just a bunch of tag_id for 'love'

```
$cl->setGroupDistinct('tag');
$cl->setGroupBy('tag', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR);  
$cl->SetLimits( 0, 10, 500);
$result = $cl->query("love", 'mytags');
```

I even tried this but it didn't work as well

```
$cl->setGroupDistinct('tag');
```

I think sphinx's group by can be used to solve this but I'm pretty clueless. Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `setGroupDistinct` on the same attribute you're grouping by.  In SQL terminology that would be similar to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
FROM my_tags
GROUP BY tag
```

which as far as I can tell would only return 1 match for each tag.

I think if you just remove the call to `setGroupDistinct` or change the distinct field to be the foreign id (thus filtering out multiple identical tags attached to one entry) you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the tag and order desc.you should add extra clause to setGroupBy function.

```
$cl->setGroupBy('tag', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR,'@count desc');
$result = $cl->query('');
```